# Two function views on single template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two function views and i want them to render them on single template. These two views have different form.

```
def user_query(request):
    form_user = Search_User(request.POST)
    no_user = "User Not Found"
    if form_user.is_valid():
        user_name = str(form_user.cleaned_data['user_name'])  
        query = WatchedVideo.objects.filter(user = user_name)
        data_source = ModelDataSource(query,fields=['videoData_id', 'time'])
        pie_chart = gchart.PieChart(data_source,options={'title': user_name + "Video Data"})
        context = {
                'form_user' : form_user,
                "data_source": data_source,
                "pie_chart": pie_chart,
                }
        return render(request,'chart2.html', context)

def select_chart_form(request):
        form = SelectChart(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        chart_type = str(form.cleaned_data['status_chart_type'])
        if (str(form.cleaned_data['status_chart']) == '1'):
            analysis = VideoData.objects.annotate(watches_count = Count('user')).order_by('-watches_count')[:10]
            data_source = ModelDataSource(analysis,fields=['video_name', 'watches_count'])
            column_chart = gchart.ColumnChart(data_source,options={'title': "Top 10 Videos watched by No. Of Users"})
            pie_chart = gchart.PieChart(data_source,options={'title': "Top 10 Videos watched by No. Of Users"})
            context = {
                'form_record' : form_record,
                'chart_type' : chart_type,
                'form' : form,
                "data_source": data_source,
                "column_chart": column_chart,
                "pie_chart": pie_chart,
            }
            return render(request,'chart2.html', context)
```

above is my two function view which i want to render on single url
How can i do that?

Comment: do you mean "how do I manage to show the two different forms in the same template"? If so, please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

Comment: @Pynchia that doesn't seem to be related to the question at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman OK. I meant does the OP want to use one form only in the template to show either forms?

Comment: @Pynchia i have defined two class in my form.py and using them in different views now the question in url.py can a same pattern call different views because these 2 views contain different forms which i want to show on single templete..

Comment: ehm.. there should be no need to use the same url. I do this often with edit/create forms. Setup two separate urls that point to each view function. Unless there are other reasons to want them all in one url... Then I give up and let others step in to see what the way forward is. I have removed my answer, since it sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @Pynchia ok i will create different urls for both views but how will i show i both forms in same template..

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Well you got to call both function into one:

```
def mixin(request):
    context = {}
    context['user_query'] = user_query(request, mix=True)
    context['select_chart_form'] = select_chart_form(request, mix=True)
    return render(request,'chart2.html', context)

def old_view(request, mix=False):
   "your_code"
   if mix:
       return context
   else:
       return render(request,'chart2.html', context)
```

This way you can keep using your old views the same way or in the mixin way.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if the goal is simply to use the same template for two different forms, there is no need to use the same url.

Setup two separate urls that point to each view function.

In your views, you can add a parameter to the context in order to customize the appearance of the form elements (e.g. the text on the submit button) or other specific behavior of the template

```
context['user_query'] = True # False in the other view
return render(request,'chart2.html', context)
```

Then in the template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ user_query|yesno:"UserQuery,SelectChart"}}">
</form>
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) for more details and options on how to show form elements in the template

**Note:** in the `user_query` view function, make sure the form is passed along with the same name it has in the `select_chart_form` view function:

```
context = {
        'form' : form_user,
        "data_source": data_source,
        "pie_chart": pie_chart,
        }
```

Comment: what if there are more then two view will above method work??

Comment: yes, of course. Forms can be displayed independently of their composition, as the [link I have included](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) describes

Comment: i went through link and i am not getting much how this will help me....i am accessing form using field name in html eg-: {{form.chart_type}}

Comment: I am sorry but I am about to leave the office. You can refer to form field by name only if the name is shared among the two forms. Or you can use [if](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#if) on the parameter you added to the context to discriminate

Comment: what i did is i created two templates for both view to render graphs but inheriting from base template, now i want to add these form object to call in base template do i need to make context global ???